# Linking.openUrl to send an sms in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, sms, deep-linking

I need to send an SMS with a prefilled body in a React-native app but I'm having trouble passing the phone number

This is what I have tried so far:

`Linking.openURL(sms:/open?addresses=${phone}&body=${body})`

`Linking.openURL(sms:${phone}&body=${body})`

`Linking.openURL(sms:/?addresses=${phone}&body=${body})`

The sms App opens and the body is in the message filed but the To: field contains 'No Name' with a spiner.

*this is on the latest version of IOS (13.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the simulator it works on a real device and as [Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12202977/bug) mentioned the correct syntax is indeed

`` Linking.openURL(`sms:${phone}&body=${body}`) ``

Comment: Absolutely. It works fine on a real iOS device.